how can we run adb.exe command inside flutter test code?
I'm trying to run the adb.exe command inside flutter test code.
but I'm always getting an error.
is it possible to run adb.exe inside flutter test code?
`    Future<void> runAdbCommand(List<String> arguments) async {
        final result = await Process.run('c:/Users/<user.name>/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe', arguments);
        if (result.exitCode != 0) {
        throw Exception('Failed to run adb command: ${result.stderr}');
      }
      print(result.stdout);
    }

void main() {

  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  setUpAll() async {
    await runAdbCommand(['shell', 'pm', 'grant', 'com.package.name', 'android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS']);
  }

  group('end-to-end test', () {
    testWidgets('Test App',
        (WidgetTester tester) async {
  
      app.main();
  })})
}`

I was expecting the adb.exe command to be executed.
but I got this error instead:
Error running adb command: ProcessException: No such file or directory
Command: C:/Users/<user.name>/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe shell pm grant com.package.name android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS

i dont want to put a real name there, so it was replaced with a real valid user name when running the code, thanks for the comment

Are you sure the adb code part is executed on Windows and not already on the Android device?

u r right, the adb code part is executed on the android device, but how can we execute it on windows then?
